# sql - how to group by joined table

Tags: mysql, sql

My Schema is:

```
- StockPart
    id
    title
    ...
- StockItem
    id
    shipment_id
    stock_part_id
    status
    ...
- Shipment
    id
    item_cost
    ...
```

I'm using this query to get a list of DeviceParts and its information.

```
SELECT
    `stock_parts`.`id`,
    `stock_parts`.`title`,
    COUNT(stock_items.id) AS qtyAvailable,
    SUM(shipments.item_cost) AS totalCost
FROM
    `stock_parts`
LEFT JOIN `stock_items` ON `stock_items`.`stock_part_id` = `stock_parts`.`id` AND ( `stock_items`.`status` IS NULL )
LEFT JOIN `shipments` ON `shipments`.`id` = `stock_items`.`shipment_id`
GROUP BY
    `stock_parts`.`id`,
    `stock_parts`.`title`,
    `shipments`.`id`
ORDER BY
    `stock_parts`.`title` ASC
```

So it's repeating items this way:

```
stockPart.id   |   stockPart.id     |   qtyAvailable   |     totalCost
174            |   ALTO FALANT 5C   |         1        |     1.00
174            |   ALTO FALANT 5C   |        10        |     100.00
```

The problem is related to StockItem and Shipment... because I StockItems can be related to different Shipments with different `item_cost` values.

In this case, I'd expect a single with sum values:

```
        174   |   ALTO FALANT 5C   |   11  |   101.00
```

How can I do it? Should I group something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shipments.id`  is not required in aggregation through which you are getting multiple entry as you said :

> The problem is related to StockItem and Shipment... because I StockItems can be related to different Shipments with different item_cost values

```
SELECT `stock_parts`.`id`, `stock_parts`.`title`,
        COUNT(stock_items.id) AS qtyAvailable,
        SUM(shipments.item_cost) AS totalCost
FROM `stock_parts` LEFT JOIN 
     `stock_items` 
      ON `stock_items`.`stock_part_id` = `stock_parts`.`id` AND 
         ( `stock_items`.`status` IS NULL ) LEFT JOIN 
      `shipments` 
      ON `shipments`.`id` = `stock_items`.`shipment_id`
GROUP BY `stock_parts`.`id`,`stock_parts`.`title`
ORDER BY `stock_parts`.`title` ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `shipments.id` from your `GROUP BY` clauses.
You should only do `GROUP BY` for the fields that you want to select without an aggregate function, which in your case are just `stock_parts.id` and `stock_parts.title`.